# How do I make a Juju Charm's revision match the Bazaar revision of its repo?

Tags: juju, charms

I've got a Juju Charm that is stored in a Bazaar repository and I would like the charm revision file to have the same value as the Bazaar repository's revision number.  Is there a way to make Juju "compile" the Charm and check Bazaar for the revision number?  Basically I want `bzr revno > revision`.

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

The bzr-keywords plugin should be able to do this for you:

- http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/KeywordExpansion

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't really work because everyone who would checkout the charm would need to have that plugin, including things like the charm store.  Otherwise people would get an invalid charm and not be able to use it.